# Recommendations on how to buy Bitcoins with limit orders

Tags: buy-bitcoins, exchange-order

I live in the US, have US bank accounts, and would like to buy Bitcoins, but with limit orders, e.g. place a limit order for 1 BTC = US$500 or less, and wait for several weeks to see it fulfilled.

What are reasonable options for me?  I know that Mt. Gox offers such limit orders, but to get money to them requires expensive and time consuming international wire transfers.

An ideal solution would enable to me to place a limit order to buy Bitcoins with a transfer from my US bank account.  I can easily transfer USD from my US bank account with ACH or a US wire transfer.  However, I am open to any reasonable solutions.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is no longer applicable, since CampBX is shutting down.

<s>[CampBX](https://campbx.com) offers limit orders, and allows US residents to deposit dollars by mailing postal money orders, or (after a verification process) personal checks.</s>

Comment: Thanks.  I looked into CampBX, but there were many complaints about customer service and unpredictable deposits and withdrawals.

Comment: @KevinP.: Ok.  I personally have used them with no problems, though I have not tried USD withdrawals.

Comment: After looking around, I could not find any other workable options, so I have signed up with CampBX and sent them my KYC docs.  Their ability to take a personal check is certainly very valuable.  Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2):

I used Coinbase.com to buy BTC with USD which cleared in 4 days.  Then I sent my BTC to MtGox which took about 30 min.  The only downside to Coinbase is that when you buy bitcoin with USD you lock in at that BTC price and can't touch it for 4 days, i.e. no opportunity for stop loss.  I was fortunate in that BTC went up in price while I was waiting.

Ideally I would have liked to send USD to coinbase, then 4 days later buy BTC if the technicals looked right along with a corresponding stop loss limit order.  USD to BTC is certainly less than ideal but once you've got BTC, very fun to trade.